# Can't install NuGet package on a blank solution in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

At my company we have a NuGet package that, when applied on a blank Visual Studio solution, will generate a solution template with a predefined set of properly named and configured projects. We install the package by just executing the regular `Install-package` command in the package manager console.

However this seems to have been stopped working in Visual Studio 2015. If I try to install the package I get this error:

```
install-package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package (The package name)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

What puzzles me is that this was working fine in Visual Studio 2013. I have been looking for information about this behavior but I haven't seen it mentioned nor reported as a bug anywhere.

Does anyone know what is happening here? Is it a bug? Is it a change in the way NuGet works in VS 2015?

By the way, if it matters, the VS 2013 edition I am using is Professional, while the VS 2015 edition is Community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that [solution level packages are deprecated in Visual Studio 2015](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1076#issuecomment-126481782), so no real solution for this.

Comment: ...which I find very unfortunate. Why removing a feature that is useful and doesn't harm? We will have to trash our solution template package and research an alternative solution, or keep VS 2013 installed forever!